# Arrays En Clausula IF Bash Script

Tags: bash, condiciones

Buen día, es posible utilizar en una sentencia if de Bash script un array?, soy muy novato en lo que respecta a Bash y tengo el siguiente código que busca condicionar en una sentencia if una lista de fechas, para luego copiar un archivo y pasarlo a otra ruta, el problema es que este copiado se realiza tantas veces como se ejecuta el ciclo for, es posible  condicionar en un if un array y que solo realice una vez el copiado si todas las condiciones se cumplen?  de antemano gracias por la ayuda.

```
#!/bin/bash  
fecha_ayer=$(date -d yesterday '+%Y%m%d')  
fecha_hoy=$(date '+%Y%m%d')  
dia_actual=$(date +%w -d $fecha_hoy)  
fecha2=$(date "-d -2 days" '+%Y%m%d')  
FESTIVO[0]=$anonuevo  
FESTIVO[1]=$epifania  
FESTIVO[2]=$SanJose  
FESTIVO[3]=$juevessanto  
FESTIVO[4]=$viernessanto  

for i in ${FESTIVO[@]};do  
  if [[ $dia_actual -eq 2 ]] && [[ $fecha_ayer -eq $i ]];then  
   for archivo in /ruta/de/mi/archivo/nombrearchivo_$fecha2_*;do  
    cp $archivo /home/Pruebas/  
   done  
  fi  
done
```

Comment: Hola @JUANMATACHIN, acostumbra a poner el código pegado como texto y no una imagen del mismo. Es una mala costumbre que no gusta mucho enla comunidad. Date cuenta que si alguien desea probar tu código para ver los posibles errores o desarrollar una solución, tendrá que escribir de nuevo todo el código. Si lo pegas como texto, simplemente se podrá copiar y usar. Un saludo

Comment: Buen dia.  mis disculpas, queda editada la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que tu archivo no se copie tantas veces como se ejecuta el for, simplemente puedes copiar el archivo solo si el archivo no existe:

```sh
#!/bin/bash  
fecha_ayer=$(date -d yesterday '+%Y%m%d')  
fecha_hoy=$(date '+%Y%m%d')  
dia_actual=$(date +%w -d $fecha_hoy)  
fecha2=$(date "-d -2 days" '+%Y%m%d')  
FESTIVO[0]=$anonuevo  
FESTIVO[1]=$epifania  
FESTIVO[2]=$SanJose  
FESTIVO[3]=$juevessanto  
FESTIVO[4]=$viernessanto  

for i in ${FESTIVO[@]};do  
  if [[ $dia_actual -eq 2 ]] && [[ $fecha_ayer -eq $i ]];then  
   for archivo in /ruta/de/mi/archivo/nombrearchivo_$fecha2_*;do
     # Aqui preguntamos si el archivo no existe en el directorio hacia
     # donde lo quieres copiar y en caso de que no exista copielo.  
     if  [ ! -f "/home/Pruebas/$archivo" ]; then
       cp $archivo /home/Pruebas/
     fi  
   done  
  fi  
done
```

Asumo la opción `-f` creyendo que quieres copiar archivos comunes (.txt, .sh, .jpg, .docx, etc), pero si tu archivo es un directorio u otra cosa, puedes ver en [este](https://bioinf.comav.upv.es/courses/unix/scripts_bash.html#condicionales-con-archivos) enlace las demas operaciones que puedes ejecutar sobre un archivo, ya sea uno comun, un directorio, un dispositivo de bloques, enlace simbolico, etc.

Comment: Buen día @AgileSoul con tu ayuda y la de la comunidad pude completar mi Script, muchas gracias  por resolver mi duda, fue muy útil el conocimiento aprendido

Comment: Gracias a ti por preguntar, puedes seguir preguntando para que sigas creciendo, que aquí intentaremos resolver tus dudas.

Answer (score 3):

Para usar un array en un condicional, puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
# definimos un array con los días de la semana
array=(lunes martes miercoles jueves viernes sabado domingo)

#creamos una variable de ejemplo
dia5=viernes

#creamos un bucle que recorra el array
for k in "${array[@]}"
do

    # comprobar si el array contiene los elementos 
    if [ "${k}" == "lunes" ]; then
        echo "contiene el elemento 'lunes'"
    fi

    if [ "${k}" == "miercoles" ]; then
        echo "contiene el elemento 'miercoles'"
    fi

    if [ "${k}" == "${dia5}" ]; then
        echo "contiene el elemento 'viernes'"
    fi
done
```

Con tu código me faltarían las fechas de las variables de los días del array. Para hacer una similitud, empleo texto plano

```
#!/bin/bash  
fecha_ayer=$(date -d yesterday '+%Y%m%d')  
fecha_hoy=$(date '+%Y%m%d')  
dia_actual=$(date +%w -d $fecha_hoy)  
fecha2=$(date "-d -2 days" '+%Y%m%d')  

FESTIVO=(ano_Nuevo epifania San_Jose jueves_Santo viernes_Santo)
#FESTIVO=("${ano_Nuevo} "${epifania} "${San_Jose} "${jueves_Santo} "${viernes_Santo})

for i in ${FESTIVO[@]};do  

    if [ "${i}" == "epifania" ]; then  
        echo "contiene el elemento epifania"
    fi  

    if [ "${i}" == "jueves_Santo" ]; then  
        echo "contiene el elemento Jueves Santo"
    fi  
done
```

EDITADA

Puedes jugar con los condicionales y variables booleanas

```
# definimos un array con los días de la semana
array=(lunes martes miercoles jueves viernes)

#creamos unas variables de ejmplo
dia3="miercoles"
dia6="sabado"
dia7="domingo"

#declaramos dos variables booleanas a falso
v3=false
v6=false
v7=false

#creamos un bucle que recorra el array
for k in "${array[@]}"
do

    # comprobar si el array contiene el elemento
    if [ "${k}" == ${dia3} ]; then
        #ponemos la variable a true
        v3=true
    fi
    # comprobar si el array contiene el elemento
    if [ "${k}" == ${dia6} ]; then
        #ponemos la variable a true
        v6=true
    fi

    # comprobar si el array contiene el elemento
    if [ "${k}" == ${dia7} ]; then
        #ponemos la variable a true
        v7=true
    fi

done

#si tenemos la variable a false, o sea, si no aparece el valor en el     array
if [ ${v3} == false ]; then
    #lo imprimimos en pantalla
    echo "${dia3} no está"
fi
#si tenemos la variable a false, o sea, si no aparece el valor en el array
if [ ${v6} == false ]; then
    #lo imprimimos en pantalla
    echo "${dia6} no está"
fi
#si tenemos la variable a false, o sea, si no aparece el valor en el array
if [ ${v7} == false ]; then
    #lo imprimimos en pantalla
    echo "${dia7} no está"
fi
```

Comment: Hola @el.trasgu , aplique tu consejo y pude obtener lo que necesita, mil gracias, funciono a la perfección

Comment: Hola @el.trasgu me surgió la siguiente duda, y si en vez de comprobar si un elemento está dentro de un arreglo, quiero utilizar el condicional para que me compare si un valor no está dentro del array, en este caso y tomando tu ejemplo, el echo se iteraria tantas veces como número de elementos tiene el arreglo, hay alguna manera de que solo itere una vez si el valor no se encuentra dentro del array?

Comment: Te puse un ejemplo editando mi respuesta. espero te sirva

Comment: Hola @el.trasgu, por supuesto que tu ayuda fue muy útil, pude resolver mi  problema, muy agradecido por el tiempo que me ha brindado

Comment: Hola @JUANMATACHIN, gracias, pero es la razón de estar en la comunidad, prestar esa ayuda que en algún momento todos hemos necestiado. Un saludo